# Xorgxrdp: possible to connect to local desktop?

Tags: centos, rdp, xorg, xrdp

I've compiled and installed xrdp and xorgxrdp on Centos 7.4. Everything works fine. One feature I like to know if possible is whether we can use xorgxrdp to remotely connect to the current desktop. Right now out of the box, it creates a new session. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

You can potentially use x11vnc as the backend to connect to an existing X session.

Used 'directly' from the command, line, run the following to check you can connect to your existing session (replacing `:0` with the number of your current X display):

```
x11vnc -noxdamage -display :0 -safer  -once
```

If that works, then the following config should hopefully be enough to connect to x11vnc through xrdp (untested config though, so it might need tweaking!):

```
# xrdp.ini
[xrdp1]
name=X11vnc
lib=libvnc.so
ip=127.0.0.1
port=5900
username=ask
password=ask

# sesman.ini
[X11vnc]
param=x11vnc
param=-noxdamage 
param=-display
param=:0
param=-safer
param=-once
```